# TD 6.2 IDE compatibility

Tags: centura

Is Gupta Team developer 6.2 compatible with Windows 10 ?
We are upgrading our systems from windows 7 to windows 10 and we have centura version 6.2. Do we have to upgrade the Centura to a higher version or will Windows 10 support the current version?

Comment: Handy hint to a new contributor.....If you find an answer to your question is covered and helpful, then don't forget to upvote it. It encourages those who make the effort to help you, to be helpful again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes TD6.2 works fine with Windows 10 in my experience*

Your question refers to 'Gupta TeamDeveloper' and then reverts to 'Centura version 6.2' . There is no such thing as 'Centura' anymore ever since v1.5, unless you are talking about a 16bit version.

*So assuming you actually do mean Gupta TeamDeveloper v6.2 --> 32 or 64bit , then  yes it works fine with Windows 10. Of course, TD6.2 is way past end-of-life support, so you wont get much help from Gupta on this, as the latest supported version is TD7.3

Thoroughly recommend you visit our Gupta TeamDeveloper Forum here: 
[Team Developer SQLWindows Community Forum](https://forum.tdcommunity.net/index.php)  ( register and you get more options ) where you can get expert help/advice etc.

Go here for version information and compatibility matrix for each:   [Version Info and Compatibility Matrix](https://wiki.tdcommunity.net/index.php/Team_Developer_versions)   .  Note that 6.2 on Win10 is not certified by OpenText, but it seems to work anyway.

Comment: ...and if you find the answer to your question is covered and helpful, then don't forget to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Gupta 6.2, but 5.2 has issues on Windows 10. I have migrated to 7.1.2 and have had no issues since.

If you can do so, i'd seriously consider upgrading to a newer version, the quality of life improvements are well worth it.

Comment: Good advice Tomáš.   As at 25/06/2020,  TD 7.3.0 is the latest release and TD 6.2 has been categorized as 'beyond end-of-life'.    Sushree does not specify the dBMS, but if using Oracle, TD 7.3 is certified with Oracle 19c on Windows 10. The only version that is. Go here for version information and compatibility matrix for each:   https://wiki.tdcommunity.net/index.php/Team_Developer_versions    Note that 6.2 on Win10 is not certified by OpenText, but it seems to work anyway.