# TD 6.2 and Windows 10 compatibility

Tags: guptateamdeveloper

Asked by Sushree under the 'Centura' tag. :

Is Gupta Team developer 6.2 compatible with Windows 10 ? We are upgrading our systems from windows 7 to windows 10 and we have Centura version 6.2. Do we have to upgrade the Centura to a higher version or will Windows 10 support the current version?

Answer (score 0):

Asked and answered under the 'Centura' Tag. The 'GuptaTeamDeveloper' tag is more appropriate,
so included here is a Link to it for anyone needing help on Gupta Team Developer version compatibility .
[TD 6.2 and Windows 10 compatibility is answered here:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62401661/1578254)